# Is Django built-in authentication design for managing product's users?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

Is is safe to use Django's built-in auth to manage product's users?

Or should implement my own solution, or use a 3rd party one?

Comment: I do not really get the question. Of course one can not *guarantee* that a login system is safe, but usually writing your own will not be better than what is provided, since django has been reviewed by many eyeballs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's auth system can be made to be secure or insecure based on the configurations which you specify.  With that being said, and to the heart of your question - the standard Django Auth System out-of-the-box is secure and can be enhanced by following their guidance.

More details:

- [password strength](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/)
- [historical vulnerabilities](https://www.upguard.com/articles/top-10-django-security-vulnerabilities-and-how-to-fix-them)
- [security best practices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/security/)

You asked a broad question, so it merits a somewhat broad response.  But specifically I'd use the standard Django auth vice trying to roll my own.  Its secure and is easier to maintain.